# How to add a line with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to add a line after heading with itext 2.1.7, like

[image]

Here is what I have

```
LineSeparator lsHeading = new LineSeparator();          
lsHeading.setPercentage(100);
lsHeading.setLineWidth(10);
document.add(lsHeading);
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    LineSeparator l = new LineSeparator();
    document.add(new Chunk(l));
```

Comment: thanks your code is for itext5+,and its not working in itext 2.1.7